# Updating geoJSON file from python dict

Tags: python, dictionary, geojson

I have a large geoJSON file that feeds an election map. I have scraped a site and returned voter precinct results into a python dictionary that looks like this: `{u'605': [u'56', u'31'], u'602': [u'43', u'77']`, etc...} Where the key is the precinct number and the value list is the first candidate's votes and the second candidate's votes.

I want to update my geoJSON file - which is all of the voter precincts - with the results from the dictionary. In my geoJSON file I have the precinct number as one of my key/value pairs (like - `"precNum": 602`). How would I go about updating each shape with the results from the dictionary?

I can target and loop through the geoJSON file with something like this:

```
for precincts in map_data["features"]:
    placeVariable = precincts["properties"]

    placeVariable["precNum"] 
    #This gives me the precinct number of the current shape I am in.

    placeVariable["cand1"] = ?? 
    # I want to add the Value of first candidate's vote here

    placevariable["cand2"] = ?? 
    # I want to add the Value of second candidate's vote here
```

Any ideas would be a huge help.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your json file?

Comment: Sure. Each precinct is an object that looks like this:`{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "preNum": 40, "SHAPE_AREA": 0.0}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [Coords here]] ]}}`

Comment: see my answer. is that what you are trying to do? @JonnyD

Comment: That does it @shshank thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update it like this.

```
your_dict = {u'605': [u'56', u'31'], u'602': [u'43', u'77']}

for precincts in map_data["features"]:

    placeVariable = precincts["properties"]
    prec = placeVariable["precNum"] 

    if your_dict.get(prec): #checks if prec exists in your_dict
        placeVariable["cand1"] = your_dict['prec'][0]
        placevariable["cand2"] = your_dict['prec'][0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is confusingly worded. 
You need to identify your vars better.

Sounds like  you're trying to accumulate vote totals.
thus, you want:

- precinct 100:  [ 1, 200 ]
- precinct 101:  [ 4, 300 ]

to add into:

- [ 5, 500 ]

presume accumulator array of accum.  You can throw away the info on which votes came from where when you're just adding:

```
for vals in map_data['features'].values():
    while len(accum) < len(vals):
        accum.append(0)
    for i in range(len(vals)):
        accum[i] += vals[i]
```

Here's an example program that proves the solution:

```
>>> x = { 'z': [2, 10, 200], 'y' : [3, 7], 'b' : [4, 8, 8, 10 ] }
>>> accum = []
>>> for v in x.values():
...   while len(accum) < len(v):
...     accum.append(0)
...   for i in range(len(v)):
...     accum[i] += v[i]
... 
>>> accum
[9, 25, 208, 10]
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry Kevin that's not what I was looking to do. I want to update the information in my geoJSON file with the information in my dictionary. If my shape objeect in my geoJSON looks liek this : `{ "type": "Feature", "id": 0, "properties": { "preNum": 40, "SHAPE_AREA": 0.0}, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [Coords here]] ]}}` I want the data in the my dictionary at precinct 40 to feed into that shape object, changing the properties to `"properties": { "preNum": 40, "SHAPE_AREA": 0.0, "cand1": 70, "cand2": 14}`